# How to identificate the li-item number inside angular-directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

There is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/NDFHg/)

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] );.....
```

I need to find out the number of list item , which is under editing or bluring to manipulate by it as I need.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about replacing this part of your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/NDFHg/):

```
<li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
    {{contact.name}}
</li>
```

with this:

```
<li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
    <edit-in-place value="contact.name"></edit-in-place>
</li>
```

That way you don't have to know the index of item as `edit-in-place` directive will take place after `ng-repeat` kicks in.

Priority of `ng-repeat` directive is 1000 and default directive priority (if you don't specify it) is 0.

More abourt directive's priorities from [AngulaJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile):

> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element,
>   sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives
>   are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their
>   compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number.
>   Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
>   Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link
>   functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the
>   same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

There is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NDFHg/114/).